# How to fill form and get the URL after login with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, casperjs

I have url, userName, pasword of a site.
This site doesn't use `form` element.
So the structure is like this.

Both `username` field has  `.user_name` class while `password` field has `#passwd` id.

Moreover `login` button has `#login` id.

I know I can use jQuery with casperjs and able to inject it in the page.

I tried the following code inside

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    $(fe.u).val(user.uname);
});
```

but it doesn't work.
What else I can try?

Comment: If it's an `input`, you may use `$(".user_name").val(user.uname)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS passing variable to evaluate can't get it to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597987/casperjs-passing-variable-to-evaluate-cant-get-it-to-work), because `user.uname` is unknown inside `evaluate()`, you have to pass it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use jQuery to fill the field and submit it.
The [`sendKeys()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sendkeys) function normally works well without forms:

```
casper.then( function() 
{
     casper.sendKeys('.user_name', 'kevin', {reset: true});
     casper.sendKeys('#passwd', 'sdkfmkds123', {reset: true});
});
casper.then( function() 
{
    casper.click('#login');
});
// Get/Echo the actual URL
casper.then( function() 
{
    casper.echo(casper.getCurrentUrl());
})
```

To get the URL, call `casper.getCurrentUrl()` afterwards. In the case above the URL is echoed after the login.